# How to connect to Visual Studio Online from Visual Studio 2012 Update 4

Tags: visual-studio-2012, tfs, azure-devops

From what I have read, it is possible to connect to Visual Studio Online from Visual Studio 2012 Update 4.

However, I cannot find anything that shows how this is actually done.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

In Team Explorer, Click on Configure Team Projects. Then click on Servers. Then click Add.  Enter:  YourProjectName.VisualStudio.com

Then click connect.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You have to choose "HTTPS" instead of "HTTP" as shown above, otherwise you will fail. Maybe they changed that recently.